# jquery animation optimization

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this script for an animation on a forum.

I noticed it creates some sort of lag. Is there a better way to achieve the animation? or improve the code for a smoother experience?

```
$(function(){
    // animation Scroll
    var posY1 = 0;
    var posY2 = 0;
    var posY3 = 0;
    var imgH = 500;
    setInterval(function(){
        if (posY1 <= -900) posY1 = 0;
        if (posY2 <= -900) posY2 = 0;
        if (posY3 <= -1200) posY3 = 0;
        posY1 -= 1;
        posY2 -= 2;
        posY3 -= 3;
        $('#background').css({ backgroundPosition: '0' + posY1 + 'px' });
        $('#midground').css({ backgroundPosition: '0' + posY2 + 'px' });
        $('#foreground').css({ backgroundPosition: '0' + posY3 + 'px' });
    },50);
});
```

Comment: This would be a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: hi, isn't' stackoverflow the same thing? sorry just not really familiar with this site in general..

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [Amimate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('#background').animate({ backgroundPosition: '0' + posY1 + 'px' },time needed to perform if needed);
$('#midground').animate({ backgroundPosition: '0' + posY2 + 'px' });
$('#foreground').animate({ backgroundPosition: '0' + posY3 + 'px' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some optimize tips for your code：

$(function(){

```
    // animation Scroll
    var posY1 = 0;
    var posY2 = 0;
    var posY3 = 0;
    var imgH = 500;
    //cache jquery var
    var jqBackground = $('#background');
    var jqMidground = $('#midground')
    var jqForeground = $('#foreground');
    function doAnimation(){
      //using setimeout insteadof setinterval
      setTimeout(function(){
        if (posY1 <= -900) posY1 = 0;
        if (posY2 <= -900) posY2 = 0;
        if (posY3 <= -1200) posY3 = 0;
        posY1 -= 1;
        posY2 -= 2;
        posY3 -= 3;
        // using [].join replace '+',and jquery css method is not efficiency
        jqBackground[0].style['backgroundPosition'] = ['0',posY1,'px'].join('');
        jqMidground[0].style['backgroundPosition'] = ['0',posY2,'px'].join('');
        jqForeground[0].style['backgroundPosition'] = ['0',posY3,'px'].join('');
        doAnimation();
      },50);
    }
    doAnimation();
```

});

Comment: If your want animation more efficiency, you can use requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout.however only FF and webkit core browser support it.